# How to make empty span's hoverable?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a series of spans that all have tooltips that should be displayed if you hover over the span area. Sometimes a span will not have a value. The resulting display will be some white space where the span is meant to be that can not be hovered for the tooltip. This is understandable because the span ends up being 0x0 pixels.

All of that considered, **is there any way to make this whitespace between my "|" hoverable for the tooltips without adding extra whitespace?**

I tried some changes involving making these spans `inline-block` which does keep them in order but they still are not hoverable unless I add some `min-width` and `min-height` attribute which adds extra white space I don't want.

Probably easiest to just check this jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/en69wxgj/1/

```
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" 
title="Test Tip">
test
</span>
|
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" 
title="Test Tip">
</span>
|
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" 
title="Test Tip">
test
</span>
|
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" 
title="Test Tip">
</span>
|
```

Comment: I think you need to use your method of display: inline-block and min-width: 1em, but you can reduce the spaces between span elements by writing all code in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered injecting an invisible text with no size? It does add a bit of extra space though.

```css
.interactive-field::before {
  content: "x";
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0px
}
```

Comment: I like your idea! With one line code and `.interactive-field { display: inline-block; min-width: 0.5em; }` it works great. And i think to replace "x" with "&nbsp;"

Comment: I ended up removing the font-size: 0px because that made it have no width still on my implementation, I added a width: 1em and this looks good now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a solution using letter spacing and :before pseudo element

You can check the comparison between the original version and my version here - http://jsfiddle.net/en69wxgj/40/

---

## Steps involved:

#### 1. Reduce letter spacing between the elements

```
.parent{
  letter-spacing:-1px;
}

.interactive-field2{
  letter-spacing:0px;
}
```

I have created a parent to reduce the letter spacing between elements and have retained the letter spacing of the text

#### 2. Add a :before pseudo element

```
.interactive-field2:before{
  display:inline-block;
  content:"";
}
```

For now, it adds a pseudo element to all the spans. You can use JS to only define pseudo elements for the spans with no content in them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using flex model. You can set the container's width.

```js
    $("body").tooltip({
        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
    });
```

```css
.span-area {
  background: #f0f;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.span-area span {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="span-area">
  <span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test Tip">
test
</span>
|
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test Tip">
</span>
|
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test Tip">
test
</span>
|
<span class="interactive-field" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test Tip">
</span>
|
</div>
```